# let script find path of itself

Tags: bash, scripting, path

I want to have a bash-script discover its own path.

The background is that I have a script called `process_scanned_text.sh`, which itself uses the script [`curves`](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/curves/index.php).
I put `curves` in the same directory as `process_scanned_text.sh`. I created a symlink to `process_scanned_text.sh` in my `~/bin` folder. Now I don't know how to correctly call the `curves` script. As it is not in `$PATH`, I need to specify it's path. Using dot as path is not correct as this points to the directory from which I call `process_scanned_text.sh`. Using `dirname $0` does not work either as this points to my `bin` folder (where the symlink is).

Comment: Try `dirname $(readlink -f $0)`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, that's the answer, you should add an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Linux systems that have GNU coreutils installed, or on FreeBSD >= 8.3:

In a shell script, call `readlink -f "$0"` to find the canonical pathname of the script, which will resolve any symlinks. Call `dirname` on that to get its directory name.

Comment: The `-f` option does not seem to be portable.